# How to find the top three column totals using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Trying to sum all columns in my table and to find the top 3 of them.

columns have only a value of **1** or **0**. That's why I am trying to sum the all inputs to compare them with each other.

I've stucked with order by code integrated into sum()

```
SELECT (ID)
FROM Student
ORDER BY SUM(C1), SUMC(C2)...SUM(C10)
lIMIT 3
```

Comment: We are also stuck see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `union all` to calculate the sum for each column and then `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.*
from ((select 'col1', sum(col1) as s from t) union all
      (select 'col2', sum(col2) as s from t) union all
      . . . 
      (select 'col10', sum(col10) as s from t)
     ) c
order by s desc
limit 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

try -

```
    SELECT TOP 3 (ID)
    FROM Student
    GROUP BY (ID)
    ORDER BY SUM(C1), SUMC(C2)...SUM(C10) DESC
```

Comment: Note that OP is using MySQL.