# Finding sum of top two columns and how much points they have?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Trying to find top 2 column with sum function.

Columns can be either **0** or **1** integer value.

Table can be seen as:

```
ID  C_ONE C_TWO C_THREE
1     1     1     0
2     0     1     1
3     1     1     0
4     0     0     0
5     1     1     0
```

**C_TWO** column has ***4*** points and **C_ONE** column has ***3*** points which are the top 2 columns and their values respectively.

I have stucked with this codes.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY SUM(C_ONE), SUM(C_TWO), SUM(C_THREE)
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326146/how-to-find-the-top-three-column-totals-using-sql

Comment: That's not someone.. that's _sameone_

Comment: Someone familiar, tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select c.col,
       (case when c.col = 'col1' then t.col1
             when c.col = 'col2' then t.col2
             when c.col = 'col3' then t.col3
        end) as cnt
from (select sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3) as col3
      from t
     ) t cross join
     (select 'col1' as col union all
      select 'col2' as col union all
      select 'col3' as col
     ) c
order by cnt desc
limit 2;
```